# Perl: Insert foreign characters into Oracle

Tags: oracle, perl

I'm having a hard time inserting special characters (accent characters, symbols, etc..) into my oracle database. I can print the data on the screen, but when I insert into the database I simply just get boxes. The tab delimited file is utf-16 encoded by default and I set the std output to utf-8. I'm thinking I might need to encode it before inserting it to the database, but I don't know how. I tried different things but with no luck. Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
use DBI;
use DBD::Oracle;
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';

#connection string here
$db = DBI->connect($dataSource, $dbUser, $dbPasswd);
$db ||  die "Error connecting to db: $DBI::errstr\n";


if(open($fh, "<:encoding(UTF-16)", $filename)){
   while (my $row = <$fh>){
                chomp $row;
                my @responses = split (/\t/, $row);
            for(my $i=17; $i<46; $i++){
               my $clob = $responses[$i];
               my $insert = "insert into myTable (id, data) values (?,?)";
               my $insert_detail = $db->prepare($insert) || die "\nPrepare error: $DBI::err .... $DBI::errstr\n";

               $insert_detail->execute('123', $clob);  
            }
   }

}
```

Comment: Did you Set NLS_LANG variable?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the answer but I also faced similar issue. This is how I solved it. Beware I am reading the whole file in memory. You can try the similar thing and see if it helps.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode qw( encode decode );

my $log_file = "test.log";
open(my $input, "<:raw", $log_file) or die "Can't open $log_file for reading: $!";
my $raw_data = do { local $/; <$input> };

my $decoded_data = eval { decode('UTF-16', $raw_data, Encode::FB_DEFAULT) };
if (!defined $decoded_data) {
    die "Exception occur while decoding log : $@";
}
my @file_data = split("\n", $decoded_data);
```

Comment: That's just a really complicated way of doing what the OP does with `:encoding(UTF-16)`

Answer (score 0):

I's duggest you to check database NLS parameters with the following

```
select * from v$parameter where name like 'nls%'
```

this will show the encoding as well.

Then you need either to change the encoding parameter in the perl script or set up the environment variable named NLS_LANG for the environment you are running code from

[Here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-nls-lang.html) you can check on how to set NLS_LANG variable

Comment: The query does not show the database character set. It is a common myth that you have to set `NLS_LANG` to database character set. Maybe read the pages before you provide the link: ***Common NLS_LANG Myths:**

    Setting the NLS_LANG to the character set of the database MAY be correct but IS often not correct. DO NOT assume that NLS_LANG needs to be the same as the database character set. THIS IS OFTEN NOT TRUE.*

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit "often" not "always". According to my experience it happens and could be the issue here

Comment: Yes, this is getting really close. I added the Env variable and it appears like almost all the characters imported successfully except Asian charset  (ex.,  서울 외환시장에서).

Comment: @loulou glad to help. May I ask you upvote my answer then so the other won't see the negative rating for an answer that is helpful?
(I don't ask to mark it as an answer since it did not resolve the issue completely)